# matrix product of two positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

If $A>0$ , $B>0$

**what are conditions on $A , B$ to conclude $AB>0$.**

Comment: Positive definite means for a matrix $A$, it's positive definite if $xAx>0$ for all possible values for the vector $x$.

Comment: If $A>0$ and $B>0$? No additional conditions! The sum of positive numbers multiplied with positive numbers will be positive...

Comment: @JeremiasK The tag positive-definite rather suggests this is not about entry-positive matrices...

Comment: Does your definition of positive definiteness include symmetry/hermitian?